# Scaling mesh from center

Tags: java, libgdx, lwjgl

I've successfully created a `Mesh` from a grid of vertices. Each vertex is a 2d vector and is backed by a physics `Body` which has a small radius. Due to this, my object onto which I try to map the `Mesh` with a texture doesn't get completely covered.

Illustration of the problem (notice that the object is not completely covered by the texture):

[image]

This is the code I use to set the position of each vertex for the mesh (variable `center` is the center of the rendered mesh, also note that the mesh can be rotated in any direction):

```
int idx = 0;

for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        float u = (float) i / (width - 1);
        float v = 1 - (float) j / (height - 1);

        Vector2 pos = bodies[i][j].getLocalPoint(center);

        vertices[idx++] = center.x - pos.x; // x
        vertices[idx++] = center.y - pos.y; // y
        vertices[idx++] = u;
        vertices[idx++] = v;
    }
}
```

This is how I instantiate the mesh:

```
Mesh mesh = new Mesh(
        false,
        vertices.length,
        indices.length,
        new VertexAttribute(Usage.Position, 2, ShaderProgram.POSITION_ATTRIBUTE),
        new VertexAttribute(Usage.TextureCoordinates, 2, ShaderProgram.TEXCOORD_ATTRIBUTE)
);
```

And later set the vertices and render it:

```
mesh.setVertices(vertices);
mesh.render(shaderProgram, GL20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
```

I've been trying to solve this issue for a while, so far I've tried extending and scaling the local position vectors by a constant radius value, but these attempts produced a deformed *bloby* mesh.

Questions:

1. How should I offset each position vector in order to fully cover my object with the textured mesh?
2. Are there any more efficient methods of scaling meshes rather than offsetting vertices?

Comment: Your problem is not clearly described enough for me to see what you are trying to do, but Delauney triangles might be of use for area mapping: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation. I have used it in the past for forming landscape maps in 3D.

Comment: @Jason I've updated the question a bit, maybe it will be a bit more clear. As for your suggestion, I've already mapped and created triangles for my mesh so triangulation is not the problem. What I'm actually trying to do is to find a function on how to offset each vertex of the mesh so that my object (the rectangle with circles) gets fully covered with the texture.

Comment: Would scaling the texture produce the effect you are looking for, or do you need to scale the mesh itself?

Comment: @NickClark2016 scaling the texture is also ok, but its not that simple.

I created a more generic question for this problem, so I'm guessing I should close this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43570479/extend-mesh-vertex-positions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extend mesh vertex positions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43570479/extend-mesh-vertex-positions)