# Extend mesh vertex positions

Tags: java, geometry, mesh

I have 2d points which are constantly being updated by a physics library. I know their local position and store it in an array of `vertices`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < bodies.size(); i++) {
    Vec2 pos = bodies.get(i).getLocalPoint(center);

    vertices[i * 2]     = -pos.x;
    vertices[i * 2 + 1] = -pos.y;
}
```

Each point is connected to its neighbors via springs and can be moved in any direction. Since each body is connected, the polygon as a whole can be rotated and moved as well. Example mesh:

[image: Polygon mesh]

I use these polygon positions to map a texture and do some drawing later on. Now I want to extend (grow) each vertex position, so that I could scale my mapped texture. I'm trying to achieve such result (blue dots represent extended vertices, also notice that inner vertices extend as well):

[image: Extended polygon mesh]

What I've tried:

- Multiplying each vertex by offset value, if the body rotates the vertex positions get deformed.
- Increasing magnitudes of each vertex vector by offset value based on distance from center. This works if the body is stationary, but if it rotates it deforms same as with scaling.
- Scaling using the drawing library also gives similar results as previous attempts. Since for scaling to work it requires the rotation of drawn mesh, however the mesh is already rotated and deformed.

How could I extend vertices so that they don't get deformed even when the body rotates?

**Edit**

Here is a an example of these bodies being rendered to give some context to the problem:

[image: Shape rendering]

What I would like to achieve:

[image: Shape rendering correct]

Comment: Multiplying vertex coordinates uniformly and rotation can not deform your system. How do you make this process?

Comment: You're talking about the first point if I understand your question correctly? If so upon creation of the mesh I store a value of how much I want to extend each vertex in `x` and `y` directions, then when updating `vertices` array, I do `vertices[i * 2] = -pos.x * scale.x; vertices[i * 2 + 1]     = -pos.y * scale.y;`

Comment: So coefficients by X and by Y are different? In this case (rotation + non-uniform scaling) deformation should take place. To make a form right, one have to rotate to zero angle before scaling, scale, and rotate back (build appropriate affine matrix)

Comment: @MBo Yes they can vary. I've been playing with rotation a bit, I used 3 points (top left and top right and the center) to get the angle, though it was very rough as the shape can bend and squeeze so I dropped the idea. Maybe you have some clues on how I could get accurate rotation angles for such shapes?

Comment: If rotation and scaling is due to user interaction, you'd better to make only one operation in every moment. For rigid rotation It is enough to use two points - one "pinned" - rotation center, and the second - rotation "handle"

Comment: The rotation comes from the physics library (each simulation step provides me with update vertex positions). The scaling is constant per shape.

Comment: Your `scale.x` and `scale.y` - are not equal?

Comment: No they're not equal.

Comment: So a square after rotation and scaling can transform into parallelogram, not rectangle. Is it your problem, or you do mean another deformations?

Comment: It is not clear, what you want. Do you want the blue vertices to form a rectangle? Do you want the blue vertices to cover always the same area independent of the position of the red vertices? Do you want a solution for 12 red vertices exactly connected as drawn or are you looking for a more general solution with also more/less vertices?

Comment: @MBo I tried to un-rotate the object and apply the transforms and then rotate it back. Though getting the right angle is quite difficult since each point can move around freely and is connected only via spring to its neighbors. I'm starting to think that the most appropriate solution would be to introduce _ghost_ vertices to the edges of the shape and simulate them as well.

Comment: @coproc I will add real examples of what I'm trying to do later on today.

Comment: @coproc I updated the question as I've mentioned.